# assigning angular components to buttons events

Tags: angular, typescript

In my app. I have three buttons(b1, b2, b3). The button b3 has a common functionality for buttons b1 and b2. I want to switch the logic based on the first button clicked between buttons b1 and b2.

For example:

- If I click the button1 first and then button 3 I want to log "b13".
- If I click the button 2 first and then button 3 I want to log "b23"

How to implement a specific sub-component for each button event and keep the global variables in the Main component to bind between two components?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7epjzm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I think you haven't forked the stackbiltz

Comment: can you please check it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the `Stackblitz`.

Html

```html
<div>
  <button (click)="b1Val = true">B1</button>
  <button (click)="b2Val = true">B2</button>
  <button (click)="onB3()">B3</button>
</div>
```

TS

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  b1Val: boolean = false;
  b2Val: boolean = false;

  onB3() {
    console.log(this.b1Val, this.b2Val);
    if (this.b1Val) {
      console.log('b13');
    }
    else if (this.b2Val) {
      console.log('b23');
    }

    this.b1Val = this.b2Val = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
  logString:string = 'b'

  btn1(){
    this.logString += "1"
  }
  btn2(){
    this.logString += "2"

  }
  btn3(){
    this.logString += "3"
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqe9sp?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

hello this is my code

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  buttonClickedLs = []
  s;
  btn1(num) {
    console.log("btn1");
    this.btnCLicked(num);
  }
  btn2(num) {
    console.log("btn2");
    this.btnCLicked(num);

  }
  btn3() {
    console.log("btn3");
    this.btnCLicked(3);

    // if(btn1 isclicked){console.log("btn13")}
    //  if(btn2 isclicked){console.log("btn23")}
  }
  btnCLicked(btnNum) {
    if (this.buttonClickedLs && this.buttonClickedLs.length >= 2)
      this.buttonClickedLs = [];

    this.buttonClickedLs.push(btnNum);
    if (this.buttonClickedLs && this.buttonClickedLs.length == 2) {
      var str = 'btn';
      this.buttonClickedLs.forEach(r => {
        str = str + r;
      })
      console.log(str);
    }


  }
}
```

```html
<button class="dropbtn" id="btn1_" (click)="btn1(1)">btn1</button>
<br>
<button class="dropbtn" (click)="btn1(2)">btn2</button>
<button class="dropbtn" (click)="btn3()">btn3</button>
```